# Data space after join function is "huge"

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table after using the join function has grown from two tables with 27mb and 37mb to 2930mb. This table size is too large too use further on with my project for me.

I am running on Microsoft SQL Server and after joining the two tables the data space for the table have grown considerably. There are about 40000 rows in the first table and 428 in the second. Number of rows after joining is 37000. This should be correct.

I suspect it might be because of how the data type for the column has been defined. I imported one of the tables from excel (the one with 40000 rows) and therefore the program only took a sample of the first rows to define the datatype. Some of the rows further below in the table exceeded the given data type given (mostly nvarchar(255) when some rows had about 400 characters). Therefore i changed the first column where now almost every column has a field with 300 characters in the forst row. SQL then automatically changed to nvarchar(MAX) for these columns and it worked.

The join function i used is this one:

```
SELECT * into NewTable
    FROM Table1
    JOIN Table2
    ON   Table2.Row1=Table1.Row2;
```

I would like to have the same table as result, but not larger than 50mb.
[image: The screenshot is from after the join operation]

The screenshot is from after the join operation

Comment: Please provide table-column definitions too - currently your problem description is a bit vague.

Comment: Where are you getting the sizes of the tables from?

Comment: Size of the tables or the resulting data in memory?

Comment: @SEarle1986 under object explorer i right click my table-->Properties-->Storage

Comment: @Arvo Added an image now

Comment: @MatthewEvans The storage size the table takes up. I am not quite sure if I understood you correctly

Comment: Database is not Excel :( Well, if you look in SMSS (right-click on your database) > Reports > Disk usage by table, how much unused space you have in your joined table? If you shrink data files, does something improve?

Comment: Which table of the three is increasing in Size?

Comment: @Arvo I have  3 001 088kb of data and 160kb of unused. Shrinking did not help :(

Comment: @SEarle1986 The one resulting from the join operation. With the join i create a new one which is way larger